# Fade var element gradually in javascrypt

Tags: javascript, html

How do I go from 1 opacity to 0 but gradually? I'm new to javascript and want to know how I can fade an element by clicking a button. This code is for playing and pausing a video on my website. The idea is that once you click on the play button the button gradually fades away to reveal the video. From what I understand I have already set up a variable and it works to decrease the opacity in one go but now gradually.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```html
<video loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="y-join_vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
    
<div class="play_area">
    <div>
        <img src="x-join_img.png" onclick="playVid()" id="mybtn">
    </div>
</div>

<script> 
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
    var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn")

    function playVid() { 
        vid.play(); 
        btn.style.opacity= "0.0"
    } 

</script>
```

Comment: Why use JS for something that can be done in pure CSS?

Comment: bc the same image I am using as a button acts as a play button for the video. The same button that I want to disappear as soon as its clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options, either CSS or JS

In CSS:

```
#mybtn {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 2s ease;
}

#mybtn.clicked {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Then you need to create an event listener in JS:

```
const btn = document.querySelector("#mybtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    btn.classList.toggle("clicked");
}
```

If you want a pure JS approach, try this:

```
const fadeOut = () => {
   const btn = document.querySelector("#mybtn");
   let i = +btn.style.opacity;

   i -= 0.05;   //this controls the fadeout speed
   el.style.opacity = i;

   if (i > 0) requestAnimationFrame(fadeOut);
}
```

Then you add an event listener and pass your function as a callback:

```
const btn = document.querySelector("#mybtn");

btn.addEventListener("click", fadeOut);
```

Comment: Updated the answer for a better result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use css transition:

```
<style>
  #mybtn{
    transition: opacity 1s;
  }
</style>
```